# How to access java packages in javascript

Tags: java, javascript

I am writing simple javascript.
script is

```
document.write("Before script");
var test=new java.lang.String();
test="Test"
document.write(test);
```

for the above script getting following error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: java is not defined
```

what might be the problem ?

Comment: Java != JavaScript (except for the name). You cannot access java packages from javascript from a traditional browser environment.

Comment: Java and JavaScript have nothing to do with each other.  Your code makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do declarations like:

```
var test=new java.lang.String();
```

in javascript.
Javascript does not share Java API, it is a completely different language.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access Java objects (without some other in between) from JavaScript since they are two different languages. It should also be noted "var" does not stand for "variable" but rather for "variant" since it can hold many different types in itself. This means you don't need to create a new string or int before setting it.

Comment: Well you can do so from Rhino, so it's not completely impossible.

Comment: I figured there were ways. Hadn't heard of any specific ones though. Figured I'd just leave it out.

Comment: Actually I want to parse xml for that I wrote code var factory =DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(); var builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder(); document = builder.parse(new File("E:\\order.xml")); var root = document.getDocumentElement(); document.write(root.getTagName()); I am getting error for that "Uncaught ReferenceError: DocumentBuilderFactory is not defined "

Comment: It's really not fun to read code in comments. Also, since DocumentBuilderFactory is undefined, that means you need to define it.

Comment: DocumentBuilderFactory is present in package javax.xml.parsers so I made attempt to reolve it as javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory but got error as
Uncaught ReferenceError: javax is not defined

Comment: That's because it's Java and not JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript, despite the name, is not a scripting language for Java. They have little relation to each other besides the syntax. You'll have to learn a new language to write JavaScript programs.

Your script in particular should be:

```
document.write("Before script");
var test = "Test";
document.write(test);
```

Comment: Hi @Claudiu
Actually I want to parse xml for that I wrote code
`var factory =DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();`
`var builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();`
`document = builder.parse(new File("E:\\order.xml"));`
`var root = document.getDocumentElement();`
`document.write(root.getTagName());`

I am getting error for that
"Uncaught ReferenceError: DocumentBuilderFactory is not defined "

Comment: @SachinDoiphode: yes, that's because JavaScript has nothing to do with Java. they are different languages. there is no such thin as `DocumentBuilderFactory` in javascript, because it is a different language than java. you cannot use java classes in javascript because javascript is not the java language, thus they have nothing to do with each other. they are totally unrelated. do you follow?